# How to maximize the function $f(x,y)= x^2+2y^2$ subjected to constraint $y-x^2+1=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I want to maximize the function $f(x,y)= x^2+2y^2$ subjected to constraint $y-x^2+1=0$
Using  **Lagrange multipliers** $$2x=\lambda(-2x) $$ hence $\lambda=-1$ $$4y=\lambda $$ hence $y=\frac{-1}{4}$
So the maximum is $\frac{7}{8}$ but the answer given is $2$ where am I wrong ?

Comment: No maximum, the constraint is a parabola, while $f$ is approximately the squared distance from the origin. There is a minimum, depending on exact geometry as many as three local minima, not sure here.

Comment: Note that from your first equation $\lambda$ does not have to be -1 if $x = 0$. So you need to consider this case which i believe gives the right answer.

Comment: You should also just draw a graph of $y = x^2 -1$ and pencil in the values of $f$ at a few interesting points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively rewrite the constraint as $$x^2=y+1$$ so that your objective function becomes $$f(y)=y+1+2y^2$$ At $y=-\frac14$ the second derivative is positive, so there is minimum instead of a maximum. So, check at the extremes. For example $$x^2=y+1 \implies y\ge -1$$ For $y=-1$ you get that $x=0$ and indeed that $f(0,-1)=0+2(-1)^2=2$. But for $y\to+\infty$ the whole expression goes to $+\infty$ so the function is actually unbounded (if you have not omitted some constraints).

Comment: Still, my answer does not give out the maximum. Can you take it from here or not?

Comment: No global maximum. Unbounded. Permitted to have more than one local minima or saddle points or local maxima, if those come up.

Answer (score 3):

Going off **dezdichado**'s suggestion,

1. $2x=λ(−2x)$, where $x = 0$

---

2. if $y = \frac{λ}{4}$, then $\frac{λ}{4} + 0^2 + 1  = 0$.
3. $λ = -4, y = -1$.
4. Plugging that into the original equation, $f(0, -1) = 0 + 2(-1)^2 = 2$.